# Laravel response return incorrect status code

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel Response is returning a incorrect status code.

I am getting a 200 response when I wanted to get a 409.

This is the method explained in the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses But is not working for me.

```
return response("Error",409) 
                ->header("Custom-Header", "CustomValue");
```

What I am missing?

Comment: And how did you test it? I just tried one on my own project, testing it with Postman it sure gave status 409. Are you reaching this point?

Comment: I am monitoring apache logs, If I do an abort(409) I get the correct status code, but I need the send a custom header.

Comment: if I try the route with this response through the browser I get Error on the page, and I cannot see the status, but with postman it gave back the correct status.

Comment: I read on another SO question that might be a space before the <?php tag. I did review all my code 2 controllers, 1 model and I don't have any space before the <?php tag.

Comment: Did you get your custom header in 200 response? And what is your custom header name?

Comment: Yes I am getting the custom header but with a 200 http response.

Comment: What about explicitly setting the status code: `response('Error')->setStatusCode(409)->header("Custom-Header", "CustomValue");`?

Comment: response('Error')->setStatusCode(409)->header("Custom-Header", "CustomValue");  and  response('Error')->status(409)->header("Custom-Header", "CustomValue");    I did try them before posting, tested again but no luck still getting a 200 response.

Comment: I am testing using Postman and all work well. Make sure that your apache log does not overrides that value somehow.

Comment: Apache log is returning the correct values. If I change to abort(409); I get the correct status:  409.

Comment: The `abort` helper allows you to send headers as the third argument. `abort(409, 'Some Message', ['custom-header'=>'custom-value']);`

Comment: What you have should work.  Anytime I had a wrong status code in laravel it typically was from middleware, or possibly a view composer.   I would go to `config/app.php`, comment out middleware, and run your code to see if anything changes.

Comment: Still having 200 status code.. workaround using header("customHeader",true,409); is giving the correct code but it's not the laravel way to do it.